# Why RDD, Dataframe and Dataset in Spark are being calling as Api?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I started reading the book called "Spark definitive guide-big data processing made simple" to learn Spark. While I was reading I saw a line saying "**A DataFrame is the most common Structured API** and simply represents a table of data with rows and columns." *I am not able to understand why are RDDs and DataFrames being called APIs?*

Answer (score 2):

They're called APIs because they're essentially just different interfaces to exactly the same data. DataFrame can be built on top of RDD and RDD can be extracted from DataFrame. They just have different sets of functions defined on that data, main differences are semantics and the way you work with data, RDD being lower level API and DataFrame being higher level API. For example you can use Spark SQL interface with DataFrame which provides all common SQL functions, but if you decide to use RDDs, you would need to write SQL functions yourself using RDD transformations.

And of course, they both exist because it really comes down to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

From the user/developer point of view, RDDs & DataFrames are just like any other objects you might deal with in your scripts, but behind the scenes those "objects" are functioning as APIs - they're interfaces through which your program can dynamically interact with specific chunks of data that lives elsewhere (and is probably distributed across multiple external linked sources).